# Filter by two values with ID column

Tags: pandas, tableau-api, data-analysis

im analyzing some e-sports soccer championship data.
My original table looks like this:
Every row corresponds to one match with the Date, Players envolved, the Teams they used and their Scores

[my df head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJPt0.png)

After seaching around tableau community, I pivoted "Player A" and "Player B" columns so i can filter for players individually. Now any match has 2 rows(one for each player on that match) and tey're unified by the 'MatchID' column:
[my tableau table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq1Zd.png)

That said, i want to build a view where the viewer could select two players and see statistics about all the matches they played against each other, like these two:

```
1- Last 10 matches info (Date, teams they played with, scores)
2- Most-frequent results like this graph:
```

[the graph i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKSLd.png)

1. Tried bringing some dimensions to colums but i really couldnt find a way to show the entire row data in a view. No idea about h2 filter from two players and take only matches where they encounter using MatchID.
2. I tried searching around and do some Calculated Fields filters, but i just went Tableau with no background in SQL, Excel or anything, just Python. So im a bit lost with so many options and ways.

If anyone could gimme directions about that i would be very happy. Thx in advice (:

Answer (score 0):

I think you should unpivot your data so you are back with 1 record per match. Then you will be able to use 2 parameters as your filters; one parameter for player 1 and the other for player 2. That would enable the user to select 2 different players.

As there's a chance the same player could be in both the Player 1 and Player 2 columns, to use as a filter is a little more complex. Your filter calculated field for the Player1 parameter would be something like:

```
[FilterParameterPlayer1]: [ParameterPlayer1] = [Player1] OR ParameterPlayer1] = [Player2]
```

And for Player2 parameter:

```
[FilterParameterPlayer2]: [ParameterPlayer2] = [Player1] OR ParameterPlayer2] = [Player2]
```

Both filter fields should be set to only show True.